# visitors count using script

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Is their any way for display visitor count on home page using vue js?
or any other script technology?

```js
if (sessionStorage.clickcount)
  { sessionStorage.clickcount=Number(sessionStorage.clic  kcount)+1;
  }
else
  {
    sessionStorage.clickcount=1;
  }
```

this display session click count only

Comment: Just use google analytics and save yourself the trouble of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visitors count you should do it server-side. Because everything you in client-side is only related to the current user only.

If you want count current user visits from the current browser:

- for this session you can use `sessionStorage`
- for all time you can use `localStorage`

Comment: Ok thnaks..it means its better to do it on server side